# Strange behavior of Flutter ImageFilter.blur

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When I use this, the edges of the container are rendered incorrectly (blurred white edges)

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j2Au.jpg)

Only the image is blurry (centered), but for some reason a blurry white line is displayed at the very top.

Any help is welcome.

Here is the code

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    toolbarHeight: 0,
    elevation: 0,
  ),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (ctx, _setState) {
      return ColoredBox(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onVerticalDragEnd: (details) {
                if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy < -100 ||
                    details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy > 100) {
                  Get.back();
                }
              },
              child: CarouselSlider(
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  viewportFraction: 1,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                  disableCenter: true,
                  autoPlayCurve: Curves.bounceOut,
                  initialPage: widget.activeSlide,
                  onPageChanged: (page, _reason) {
                    _setState(() => widget.activeSlide = page);
                  },
                  scrollPhysics: kDefaultScrollPhysics
                ),
                items: widget.post.images.map((image) {
                  return Builder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => Stack(
                      children: [
                        Center(
                          child: Image.network(
                            ApiConfig.ensureUrl(image.original) + image.original,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: ClipRect(
                            child: BackdropFilter(
                              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Image.network(
                            ApiConfig.ensureUrl(image.original) + image.original,
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ));
    }),
  ),
);
```

I expect the image to blur correctly and the edges of the container to be completely black (like its background)